# Design pattern description - What sort of smart pointer type do I need to use?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a situation where I want a 'pointer' to an object. When the object gets deleted I want all the 'pointers' to be invalidated.

If there isn't already a smart pointer class implemented to do this then I know how to implement this mechanic myself; however I'm stuck with what I should call it.

I've looked up various descriptions of pointer types including auto, unique, weak and smart and none of these fits what I'm trying to do.

Does anyone know if there is a design pattern that matches what I'm trying to do?

I could just call them 'Smart Handle' or 'Auto Invalidate Handle' (but that is a bit of mouthful). I want something that describes it's usage to most programmers, so if there is an existing design pattern I want to follow that so other programmers know exactly what the code will do.

I want to make sure I use the correct vocabulary when describing this code.

Thanks

Comment: Which programming language? It looks like to me you would want `shared_ptr` and [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) in C++ although your use case is not clear to me. In any case, you question is rather about smart pointers and not design patterns.

Comment: The C++ `weak_ptr` is exactly what you want... It doesn't guarantee the pointer points to a valid object, but has the `expired` method to ensure your pointer is valid before using it...

Comment: Looking at weak_ptr that will do the job, but not exactly how I thought it would. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to use a weak_ptr.